# How to create SPF record for many IPs (SPF longer than 255 characters)

Tags: php, arrays, dns, implode, spf

For example I have an array with this ips and want to create with my code an long spf record:

```
$array_ips = array();
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.133"; 
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.247";
$array_ips[] = "35.16.8.184";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.127";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.134";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.154";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.153";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.150";
$array_ips[] = "39.16.2.190";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.128";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.0.128";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.187";
$array_ips[] = "43.16.8.185";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.192";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.249";
$array_ips[] = "52.16.4.252";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.238";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.232";

$ips = implode(' ip4:', $array_ips);

echo "v=spf1 +a +mx".$ips." -all";
```

The spf record would be:

```
v=spf1 +a +mx ip4:32.16.8.133 ip4:32.16.4.247 ip4:32.16.8.184 ip4:32.16.8.127 ip4:32.16.8.134 ip4:32.16.2.154 ip4:32.16.2.153 ip4:32.16.2.150 ip4:32.16.2.190 ip4:32.16.2.128 ip4:32.16.0.128 ip4:32.16.8.187 ip4:32.16.8.185 ip4:32.16.8.192 ip4:32.16.4.249 ip4:32.16.4.252 ip4:32.16.4.238 ip4:32.16.4.232 -all
```

Characters: 307

The Problem is, that an SPF only can be max. 255 characters long. No possibility to add such a long string in plesk or cpanel in txt dns record. I have heared that if could be possible to do it like this `"v=spf1 .... first" "spf second string..."`.

But does it realy work?
How to do it by generating it in my example above?

Comment: you can just add multiple records

Comment: @Dagon How you mean this?

Comment: @Dagon Multiple Records???

Comment: nope i'm wrong, that's not allowed

Comment: Kitson88 has a great answer, but you can save another couple of chars; `+` is the default action so you can drop them from `a` and `mx` clauses. Also note that SPF doesn't need to be that accurate (e.g. you could use `32.16.0.0/20` for your range without exposing much) if you also sign with DKIM.

Answer (score 2):

You can break it up into multiple include's..

```
"v=spf1 mx a include:iprange1.example.com include:iprange2.example.com -all"
```

Then under each include DNS you'll have

```
iprange1.example.com = "v=spf1 ip4:32.16.8.133 ... -all"
iprange2.example.com = "v=spf1 ip4:32.16.4.238 ... -all"
```

This will gave you a lot more room because you'll be able to include 8 includes along with your mx and a

Then each include can hold 16 ip4 addresses that will get your around 128 IP addresses that your can't CIDR.

Edit - iprange1 --> iprange2 on line 2 of 2nd code snippet

Comment: But what is, if 1 IP = 1 Domain? Than your solution will not work.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like the below if your happy to allow a /24 subnet for a couple of IP's. You could even subnet it correctly if you fancied. It's cut down your list drastically anyways.

```
<?php

$array_ips = array();
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.133"; 
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.247";
$array_ips[] = "35.16.8.184";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.127";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.134";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.154";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.153";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.150";
$array_ips[] = "39.16.2.190";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.128";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.0.128";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.187";
$array_ips[] = "43.16.8.185";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.192";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.249";
$array_ips[] = "52.16.4.252";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.238";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.232";


$subnetArr = [];

foreach ($array_ips as $k=>$v ) {

    $i = strrpos($v, '.');
    $testSub = substr($v, 0, -(strlen($v) - $i));

    if (in_array("ip4:" . $testSub . ".1/24", $subnetArr)) {

        //Do something here or change condition

    } else {

        array_push($subnetArr,"ip4:" . $testSub . ".1/24");

    }
}


$ips = implode(' ', $subnetArr);
echo "v=spf1 +a +mx ".$ips." -all";
```

**Output**

```
v=spf1 +a +mx ip4:32.16.8.1/24 ip4:32.16.4.1/24 ip4:35.16.8.1/24 ip4:32.16.2.1/24 ip4:39.16.2.1/24 ip4:32.16.0.1/24 ip4:43.16.8.1/24 ip4:52.16.4.1/24 -all
```

***Edit:***

Just changed so it actually echo's SPF!

Comment: Thanks this solution is working. If it is the best solution I don't know. Because there is also the possibility to use someone that have an IP from range to use my domain for sending.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do by sub-net. Use the standard IP4 sub-net notation:

"v=spf1 ip4:192.168.0.1/16 -all"

Allow any IP address between 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.255.255.

Comment: But we don't have all ips. We get them randomly. So a add all variation is not an optimal solution or?

Comment: Yes - I wasn't sure from your example HOW random the IPs are, but you have no other solution but to allow some IPs you don;t control. The example in your question you could do `32.16.0.1/16` and cover them all, or you could add `32.16.2.1/24 32.16.4.1/24 32.16.8.1/24` to narrow it down. But you'll need some algorithm that covers all those you need.

Comment: Otherwise, can you add multiple A records for the domain? I'm presuming not, but thought I'd mention as you have +a which means it'll check those.

Comment: As defined in [RFC1035] sections 3.3.14 and 3.3, a single text DNS record (either TXT or SPF RR types) can be composed of more than one string.  If a published record contains multiple strings, then the record MUST be treated as if those strings are concatenated together without adding spaces.  For example: IN TXT "v=spf1 .... first" "second string..." but how to do it?

Comment: And...? Not sure what that's got to do with it?

Comment: In  [RFC1035] sections 3.3.14 and 3.3 stand that it must be possible to divide a long spf string in for example two parts in format: IN TXT "v=spf1 .... first" "second string..."

Comment: I have now tried it manually in plesk and it work to enter it. But how to gernerate it with the above example?

Comment: That's a different question! Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php to split a string into 255 characters?

Answer (score -2):

I have found the solution:

```
 echo "v=spf1 +a +mx ( "'.implode('" "',$array_ips).' " ) -all";
```

but the page i found it is not in enlish. (spaces are requierd and `()`)

http://www.nullpointer.at/keyword/spf/

Translated:

> The TXT record is too long. Here, in this example, the TXT record was split into several lines. The syntax for this is: brace on (then in quotation marks "first part " next line in quotation marks "second part", etc., and finally parenthesis). Important: Do not forget the blanks within each section enclosed in quotation marks: "first part" "second part" is then composed to "first partsecond part".

Comment: your solution will not work echo will output v=spf1 +a +mx ( "32.16.8.133" "32.16.4.247" "32.16.8.184" "32.16.8.127" "32.16.8.134" "32.16.2.154" "32.16.2.153" "32.16.2.150" "32.16.2.190" "32.16.2.128" "32.16.0.128" "32.16.8.187" "32.16.8.185" "32.16.8.192" "32.16.4.249" "32.16.4.252" "32.16.4.238" "32.16.4.232 " ) -all

Comment: You have to spaces after an ip not `"32.16.8.133"` instead do this `"32.16.8.133 "` <-- note the space