# How to create a Zone File SPF record for my customers to lookup when using our email service

Tags: dns, subdomain, spf, spoofing, emailrelay

Assume my ip address is 222.222.222.1 222.222.222.2
and my domain is mydomain.com

**I wish to send regular emails on behalf of my customers domain from my servers. (relaying/spoofing)**

**hence my customers will need to enter my SPF include text into their txt record (v=spf1 ...).**
The same as I add salesforce.com and others to my txt record(v=spf1 ...):

**e.g. "v=spf1 a mx ip4:222.222.222.1 ip4:222.222.222.2 include:_spf.salesforce.com -all"**

**What I don't understand is how I separate my SPF record (for sending my domains emails) with our email services SPF lookup (used by our customers)**

This nearly answers it, except it does not say how to setup the Zone file record:
[How to create SPF record for many IPs (SPF longer than 255 characters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028266/how-to-create-spf-record-for-many-ips-spf-longer-than-255-characters)

Do I setup a txt record, an A record, a CNAME record, what type of record and how. I would assume this string goes in the data value area of my record???

**e.g. "v=spf1 ip4:222.222.222.1 ip4:222.222.222.2 -all"**
and somehow it needs this subdomain **"_spf.mydomain.com"**

and then my customers txt record for SPF looks similar to this:

**e.g. "v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.mydomain.com -all"**

I am somewhat confident I am on the right track. I just do not know how it is implemented in my zone file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an email **receiver** chooses to validate a sender with SPF, it will look up `TXT` records for the sending domain (root or `@` records), and look for exactly one that starts with `v=spf1`. That record can include anything it wants. Your customers will need a record of that form, and you will need one on your domain with your own sender setup.

The root spf record can **include** any record it likes. It is common practice for email services to have SPF records at other, non-root paths (`_spf.mydomain.com` for example) for inclusion in other records.

So in your zone file, you would have something like:

```
_spf IN TXT   "v=spf1 ip4:222.222.222.1 ip4:222.222.222.2 -all"
@    IN TXT   "v=spf1 include:myownmailsender.com -all"
```

Your customers add `include:_spf.mydomain.com` to their records, and you use the `@` record to customize your own sending preferences.

Comment: Thank You.
Very Clear Answer!

A couple of follow ups:
Is it the email client or the email server validating the sender?
And when they look up the txt records with the "include:_spf.mydomain.com" will they only find the top record due to the "_spf"?

Comment: sorry I don't have quite enough points to + vote you yet!
OK I do now. :)

Comment: Sorry, client was ambiguous. Edited to reflect that the receiver validates spf. It is optional.

Comment: The receiver will recursively follow includes. They will look up `TXT example.com.` for the third party domain, and then lookup the included `TXT _spf.yourdomain.com`. They will follow all fully qualified domain names included. They will not find your own `mydomain.com` record unless it is explicity included in another domain's.

Comment: Yes of course.
You gave me exactly the right answer, ultimately the last sentence sums it up well. But your snippet is layed out perfectly I can now update my Zone file

Comment: yes, it is actually the recursive issue that has brought me here.
My customer has 14 lookups/10, and I believe my lookup is after the tenth.

Comment: But the lookup that is causing the problem is because they are using include:mail.tnz.co.nz which is causing 2 errors and 3 extra recursive lookups. but yet to confirm this with tnz.

Comment: Yes, spf resolution is tricky. If there are already 10 lookups before you, some resolvers will probably fail. They will need to remove, or "flatten" some of the includes.

Comment: You just moved to 10k+